# Swift true false condition for statements or loops

Tags: swift

In Obj-C, for statement like

```
if (100){
NSLog(@"Condition met");
}
```

100 is equivalent for YES (1). If i understand correct, that in Swift we could only use true or false inside parentheses. So, in Obj-C we can use any non-zero character to indicate that condition met and in Swift, we are only able to use Boolean values true or false?

So, following construction if (anyNonZeroVariable){ ... } would not act like if(true){ ... } in Swift?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift, "If condition" accept only BooleanType (Bool or ObjcBool). So Xcode would not accept your "if (anyNonZeroVariable)" code.

But you have to replace with a expression of boolean. like

```
if (anyNonZero > 0) {

}
```